# RecyclerView doesnt work on API 17 Android 4.2.2

Tags: android

I have a Recyclerview working on a MotoG but when i try to make it run on a device Android 4.2.2 API17 Huawei Y330-u05 the Recycleview doesn't work, the application it closes itself.
I attach my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'

}
```

and here's my Logcat message

```
11-09 19:53:04.573 1019-019/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.view.ViewAnimationUtils
                                                                                                    at com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign.SampleMaterialAdapter.animateCircularReveal(SampleMaterialAdapter.java:75)
                                                                                                    at com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign.SampleMaterialAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(SampleMaterialAdapter.java:65)
                                                                                                    at com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign.SampleMaterialAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(SampleMaterialAdapter.java:24)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:6541)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:677)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:7399)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7357)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7345)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1459)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3374)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3183)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3627)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14150)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4478)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14150)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4478)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14150)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4478)
                                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14150)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4478)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14150)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4478)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1694)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1552)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14150)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4478)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14150)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4478)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2223)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1165)
                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4962)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:966)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
                                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 19:53:04.756 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:04.756 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000C2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:04.756 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:05.258 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:05.258 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000C3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:05.259 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:05.758 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:05.758 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000C4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:05.758 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:06.259 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:06.260 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000C5, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:06.260 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:06.770 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:06.771 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000C6, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:06.771 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:07.261 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:07.263 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000C7, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:07.263 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:07.775 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:07.775 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000C8, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:07.819 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:08.264 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:08.269 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000C9, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:08.275 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:08.766 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:08.767 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000CA, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:08.767 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:09.269 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:09.269 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000CB, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:09.269 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:09.774 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:09.778 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000CC, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:09.786 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:10.277 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:10.281 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000CD, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:10.293 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:10.772 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:10.782 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000CE, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:10.782 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:11.285 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:11.290 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000CF, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:11.291 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:11.771 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:11.771 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000D0, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:11.780 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:12.299 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:12.305 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000D1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:12.321 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:12.773 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:12.773 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000D2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:12.773 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:13.274 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:13.274 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000D3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:13.274 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:13.775 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:13.776 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000D4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:13.779 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
11-09 19:53:14.276 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: processIncoming
11-09 19:53:14.276 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400000D5, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
11-09 19:53:14.277 1019-1042/com.deitel.materialdesigncardviewsrecyclerdesign D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
```

I repeat it again, it works on Motorola MotoG but not on Huawei whic is a low version

Comment: Your app is crashing, then show the logcat and relevant code please , not the Gradle file

Comment: Also, you can remove the duplicate `appcompat-v7` line

Comment: I have added the LogCat message. It works nice on Motorola but not on a low version Cricket

Comment: Right. I believe `ViewAnimationUtils` was added in a newer SDK version.

Comment: Recyclerview should work back to API 7, though

Comment: then? i don't get your answer, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the buildToolsVersion to 25.0.0
`buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"`

ViewAnimationUtils is added in Android 5.0, so try to :

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // to use ViewAnimationUtils
}
```

Comment: Not working, it says
Failed to sync Gradle project 'MaterialDesignCardViewsRecyclerDesign'
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.0
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 25.0.0 and sync project</a>

Comment: Use the `SDK Mannger` to install `Build Tools 25.0.0`

Comment: I don't have 25.0.0 i only got 25.2.2 on the sdk manager. Nevertheless when i select 25.2.2 it doesn't let me install because the button is disabled, seems it is already installed

Comment: Ok, I have installed Build Tools 25.0.0 then run the app on Huawei device and it close itself again. Seems this is not the solution

Comment: The version of 25.2.2 is the `Android SDK Tools` not the `Android SDK Build-tools`

Comment: I have followed your instruction IMXQD but don't get the application running on huawei device.

Comment: `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // to use ViewAnimationUtils
}`

Comment: According to logcat, you used the ViewAnimationUtils class, but the Android version of device is lower than Android 5.0

Comment: dont get where to place it sir?

Comment: In the file named `SampleMaterialAdapter.java`.

Comment: wow Excellent answer, nevertheless i have lost the annimation

Comment: Here is a good library.    [CircularReveal](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal)

Comment: That's what I'm using
int centerX=0;
        int centerY=0;
        int startRadius=0;
        int endRadius=Math.max(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight());

        Animator animation=ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view,centerX,centerY, startRadius, endRadius);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        animation.start();